# Selenium Webdriver for webscraping on multiple websites concurrently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on webscraping flight prices using **Selenium Webdriver**. I want my code to be able to search flight prices for multiple trips. As of now my code works for 1 destination only.

Most answers that I find online involves using a `for` loop for the specific URLs of multiple destinations, which is not applicable to my case as the URLs depend on the different destinations that I choose.

Anyone knows how I can search for these prices concurrently without waiting for individual searches to be completed? Or perhaps an even faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the [MultiPoolProcess](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) to fetch the flights concurrently. Here is an example that I have worked with selenium:

**Script to excute your selenium function:**

```py
# MultiProcess
from subprocess import Popen
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_EXCEPTION, as_completed

urls = [url1, url2, url3]
N = 4 # Number of processors that you want to use

# Execute each bot
with ProcessPoolExecutor(N) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        command = ["python", "mySeleniumScript.py", url]
        future = executor.submit(Popen,command)
        self.futures.append(future)
```

In this case your python script containing the selenium **scraper** should parse the url from the input. Like this:

**mySeleniumScript.py**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

*** Your scraper logic here ***
```

Hopefully this point you in the right direction, let me know how it went!

Comment: sorry but I'm quite new to selenium. I've tried reading the link you attached but I can't seem to understand it. From my understanding, your code would require me to  give the URLs of multiple pages in the `urls = [url1, url2, url3]
N = 4 `  section? Is that right?

Comment: also, why did we take the first argument of the script? (`url = sys.argv[1]`)

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper